# Configurable non-realtime voice changer?

Tags: gratis, linux, audio, voice

I'm individual indie game developer. My game have dialogues, but with my literally zero budget I can't hire people to record dialogues for me. I decided to record all voices by myself and use some kind of software to configure and modify voices to suit characters. Does anyone knows some non-real time free/foss voice changer that can modify voice from files and save modified voice to file ? Also, it would be nice if it has GUI, I can use command line programs but working with gui is more natural to me